# Find Rectangle of Constant Perimeter whose diagonal is maximum (My attempt with Lagrange Multipliers)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Question is to Find Rectangle of Constant Perimeter whose diagonal is maximum (My attempt with Lagrange Multipliers)  .

I took rectangle with sides $x$ and $y$  .

Since Perimeter is constant so i took $2(x+y) = 2k$  , where k is any constant

And diagonal is $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

So i took $f(x,y)$ = $x^{2}+y^{2}$

And $g(x,y)$ which is constraint as $2(x+y-k)=0$

On solving By routine Lagrange Muliplier Method i get $x = k/2 = y$  ...So rectangle is a square ..Are conditions i have taken for to apply Lagrange Multiplier is correct here ?? (i men f , g )...Thanks

Comment: pls leave comment for down voting

Comment: Your choices for $f$ and $g$ are good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach:

If the perimeter is
$2a$,
the sides are
$x$ and $a-x$.

If $d$ is the diagonal,

$\begin{array}\\
d^2
&=x^2+(a-x)^2\\
&=x^2+a^2-2ax+x^2\\
&=2x^2-2ax+a^2\\
&=2(x^2-ax+a^2/2)\\
&=2(x^2-ax+a^2/4+a^2/4)
\text{   (completing the square)}\\
&=2((x-a/2)^2+a^2/4)\\
\end{array}
$

This is maximized when
$(x-a/2)^2$ is maximized,
i.e.,  when
$x=0$ or $x=a$
(since $0 \le x \le a$)
and has a value of
$a^2$,
so
$d = a$.

If you are not allowed
to have a rectangle
with a side of length zero,
then you can get as cloase as you want,
but can never reach this value.

This is minimized when
$x=a/2$
and has a value of
$a^2/2$,
so the result is a square
with diagonal
$a/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: this is nice .thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is intuitively clear that a rectangle of constant perimeter with maximum diagonal is a very long and thin rectangle. A square sounds like a minimum rather than a maximum, so possibly you have found the minimum. However, you didn't show your working so I am not sure.

Comment: i am asking whether f and g  have taken are correct for to apply lagrange m

Comment: This intuition is not too hard to formalize actually: the diagonal of a square of perimeter $p$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2} p}{4}$ while the limiting diagonal of an arbitrarily thin rectangle of perimeter $p$ is $\frac{p}{2}$.